# Cannot configure settings for menu breadcrumbs

Tags: routes, breadcrumbs

I installed and enabled the [Menu Breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module, however I cannot access or find the configuration settings page (even when I click the configure link on the modules page). I'm currently using the STARTERKIT from [Zen](http://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme.

Is there anything else I need to enable to get it to work?

[image: Nothing is showing up under user interface]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report for [Menu Breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module and should be posted in module's [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/menu_breadcrumb?categories=All) on Drupal.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find it at `/admin/config/user-interface/menu-breadcrumb`.

If nothing appears then clear your menu caches and try again, but it's definitely there in the code.

If that doesn't fix it, then this is a problem for the [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/menu_breadcrumb?categories=All) I'm afraid.

Comment: Clearing the menu caches solved this issue. Thank you so much.